# netbeans doesn't mark TODO in error line

Tags: javascript, eclipse, netbeans, syntax-highlighting

I'm switching from eclipse with Aptana plugin to netbeans 7.1.
Is it possible to mark TODO in error line on the right with a blue dot as in eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Netbean you can't do that anymore, the only way to retrieve your tasks is to use the **Tasks Window**. Maybe you can look for a plugin to add marks in left/right margins.

Let me know if you found one up to date, I've made some search but found nothing.

Comment: For now I'm using Task Window... but I think it's not so handy

Comment: If you're used to get the mark in margins I understand that task window is not as much simple. But it offer some good tools. You can choose to show the TODO in current file/project or in all projects. You can easily see the TODO, FIXME, etc (you can custom the words that will be put in task window) at the same place. You can also custom your filter using pattern. I hope you'll get custom with this quickly ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it differs a bit in implementation from Eclipse.
(tested in Netbeans 8) click `Window > Action Items`, a log console should appear, then go to `Tools > Options > Teams > ToDo patterns`, and add or change your TODO mark pattern.
once done, you can view TODO's (or any other thing you've marked) on the Action Items console.